# Post element value to database with ajax

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

i'm a beginner with databases, ajax and php. I want a user to make a choice from a list with checkboxes and when a choice is made, the choice is sent to the database. I have this code:

```
<form method="post" action="post" class="registry-form">
<div class="list">
<div>
    <input id='label-1' type='checkbox' />
    <label for='label-1'>
    <h3>
        <span>Studio Noos Mom Bag | Urban Woollish</span>
        <span>
          <br />
          <a href="https://www.degeleflamingo.com/collections/juweeltjes-voor-mama/products/studio-noos-mom-bag-all-black-rib?variant=31254237020230" target="_blank">Bekijk product</a>
        </span>
      </h3>
    </label>
  </div>
  ...
</div>
</form>

<input type="submit" class="gift-btn" value="submit choice" />

<script>
$(document).ready(function() {

$(".list div input[type=checkbox]").change(function() {
  $(this).parent().toggleClass('checked');
});

$('.registry-form').submit( function(e) {
    e.preventDefault();

    var geboortelijst_beschrijving = $(".list .checked h3 span:first-child").html();
    console.log(geboortelijst_beschrijving);

    $.ajax({  
        type: "POST",
        url: "post.php",  
        dataType:'json',
        data: geboortelijst_beschrijving,
        success: function(data){  
            $(".list .checked").addClass('taken');
        }  
    });
    return false;
});
});
</script>
```

post.php:

```
<?php
header("Content-Type: application/json", true);
$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","root","geboortelijst");
if(!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$geboortelijst_beschrijving = $_POST['geboortelijst_beschrijving'];

//$geboortelijst_beschrijving = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['geboortelijst_beschrijving']);


if(mysqli_query($conn, "INSERT INTO geboortelijst(geboortelijst_beschrijving, geboortelijst_status)
    VALUES('" . $geboortelijst_beschrijving . "', '1')")) {
 echo '1';
} else {
   echo "Error: " . $sql . "" . mysqli_error($conn);
}

mysqli_close($conn);
?>
```

The response i get from post.php is always 200 0K, but i have no idea why the "geboortelijst_beschrijving" is not being sent to my database. This value is empty and i always and only get "1" (which of course comes from geboortelijst_status).

Anybody have some insights?

Comment: What is your `console.log` statement logging? Do you know if the data being sent in your ajax request is accurate? Depending on which browser you are using, you can use Developer tools to peer inside the request being made.

Answer (score 0):

`$(".list .checked h3 span:first-child")` is not the correct selector. This is looking for an `h3` that's contained in the checkbox element, but checkboxes aren't containers.

You want the `h3` that's a sibling of the checkbox, not a descendant, and then find the first `span` in that.

```
var geboortelijst_beschrijving = $(".list .checked").siblings("h3").find("span:first-child").html();
```

Comment: The h3 isn't contained inside the checkbox. This class 'checked' is being added to the container div with jquery. I'm sorry i didn't mention this. I'll update my post.

Answer (score 0):

Something like this

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $('.registry-form').submit( function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();

        let checkboxes=$.find("input[type='checkbox']");
        for(let i=0; i<checkboxes.length; i++)
        {
            let checkbox=checkboxes[i];
            let id=checkbox.getAttribute("id");
            if (id!=null && id.contains("label-") && checkbox.checked)
            {
                let label=$.find("label[for='"+id+"']")[0];
                if (label!=null)
                {
                    var geboortelijst_beschrijving = $(label).html();
                    console.log(geboortelijst_beschrijving);

                    $.ajax({  
                        type: "POST",
                        url: "post.php",  
                        dataType:'json',
                        data: "geboortelijst_beschrijving="+geboortelijst_beschrijving,
                        success: function(data){  
                            $(checkbox.parentElement).addClass('taken');
                        }  
                    });
                }

            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: This works for the most part, except that it doesn't get the currently clicked checkbox value. It always gets the first checkbox/label valuy. Any idea?

Comment: That's amazing! Now i only have one last question since that was the main goal of my form. Since users can select more than one item, say for example 5, right now, my database only gets populated with one record (the first checkbox that was selected). How can i get the database to get populated with 5 records, each with their values?

Comment: It should be populated with as many records as you checked with above code unless you copied the code wrong, did not match the input id with correct label for, or you put a foreign key restriction on the DB

Comment: I think i understand. I get an error with && id.contains("label-"), so i removed it. Is that necessary for the wanted functionality?

Comment: I replaced contains with includes, which now works. But the active record is still the last one clicked, all the rest is being forgotten.. See screencast: https://streamable.com/dvvzy. The success function adds the "taken" class to the parent of the checkbox. Only the last one is being added. It's the same for the records that are being added to the db. Only the last one.

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/code/tryit.asp?filename=GA4N0Q8H4YYL heres the working code